# How should I add authentication to swashbuckle?

Tags: asp.net, swagger, ws-federation, swashbuckle

I am using swashbuckle to add swagger to my asp.net mvc web api project. I see options to add OAuth2, but my website requires wsfederation. How can I require authentication to view the swagger ui with wsfederation?

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Services");
    })
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c => { });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication in the `SwaggerConfig` file is directly linked to documenting your API, and not the actual implementation, so to speak. 
So if you use the following in your swaggerConfig:

```
 c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
                .Flow("implicit")
                .AuthorizationUrl("http://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/dialog")
                .Scopes(scopes =>
                {
                    scopes.Add("read:pets", "read your pets");
                    scopes.Add("write:pets", "modify pets in your account");
                });
```

That would generate the following securitydefinition in the swagger json file

```
securityDefinitions:
  petstore_auth:
    type: oauth2
    authorizationUrl: 'http://petstore.swagger.io/oauth/dialog'
    flow: implicit
    scopes:
      'write:pets': modify pets in your account
      'read:pets': read your pets
```

To answer

> How can I require authentication to view the swagger ui with
>   wsfederation?

Just add the authentication globally in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file, something similar to the following (if you are using a MessageHandler or Filter)

```
config.Filters.Add(new WSFederationAuthentication());
```

Viewing the swagger documentation is directly webapi related.

You might have some issues though, as Swagger gets the docs client side.